# Select value = 0 if no value to select in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my code to get Total of Day

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[hipos_BC_BH_TEST]
    @From_day datetime,
    @To_day datetime
AS
BEGIN
    declare @fd datetime
    set @fd = @From_day

    declare @dt table (Day_get nvarchar(50), Total float)
    
    while @fd <= @To_day
    begin
        insert into @dt
        Select Day_get = Convert(nvarchar(10), @fd, 20), Total = sum(isnull(Total,0))
        from hipos_BH_Info 
        where Convert(nvarchar(10), Day_get, 20) = @fd
        and Cancel_Huy = 0
        group by  Day_get, Total

        set @fd = @fd + 1  --Add 1 day
    end
    Select Day_get, Total = isnull(sum(Total),0)
    from @dt
    group by Day_get
END
```

After exec from '2021-09-01' to '2021-09-10' the result is

```
Day_get Total
2021-09-01  1106000
2021-09-02  3249600
2021-09-05  316000
2021-09-07  129000
2021-09-08  1547600
2021-09-09  271000
2021-09-10  4765900
```

And I need it show day '2021-09-03' and '2021-09-04' with Total = 0 as

```
Day_get Total
2021-09-01  1106000
2021-09-02  3249600
2021-09-03  0
2021-09-04  0
2021-09-05  316000
2021-09-07  129000
2021-09-08  1547600
2021-09-09  271000
2021-09-10  4765900
```

How can I? Please help me.

p/s : I found my way, add a cmd Select with value = 0 by UNION ALL in loop

```
        UNION ALL
        Select Day_get = Convert(nvarchar(10), @fd, 20), Total = 0
```

Comment: INSERT THE dates into table variable dt first with total value 0, Then use a CROSS APPLY between dt and your table to update the total values. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ever be doing things like this in a loop. First, let's see how to generate a set for all the dates in your range:

```
DECLARE @From_day date = '20210901',
        @To_day   date = '20210910';
  
;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM n
  WHERE n <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @From_day, @To_day)
)
SELECT Day_get = DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @From_day) 
  FROM n ORDER BY Day_get;
```

Results:

```
Day_get
----------
2021-09-01
2021-09-02
2021-09-03
2021-09-04
2021-09-05
2021-09-06
2021-09-07
2021-09-08
2021-09-09
2021-09-10
```

Now you just need to *left join* those days to the data in your table. So now your (one!) query can just become:

```
;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM n
  WHERE n <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @From_day, @To_day)
),
d(Day_get) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @From_day) FROM n
)
INSERT INTO @dt(Day_get, Total)
  SELECT d.Day_get, COALESCE(SUM(h.Total),0)
  FROM d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hipos_BH_Info AS h
    ON h.Day_get >= d.Day_get
   AND h.Day_get <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, d.Day_get)
   AND h.Cancel_Huy = 0
  GROUP BY d.Day_get;
```

Also, please don't ever check for date matching by [converting dates to a string](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) and comparing the strings, and [always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)...

*Note that if your date range can exceed 100 days, [you'll need `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5111/fix-sql-server-cte-maximum-recursion-exhausted-error/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).*

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `group by` and swap `isnull` and `sum` in selecting data

```
insert into @dt
Select Day_get = Convert(nvarchar(10), @fd, 20), Total = isnull(sum(Total),0)
from hipos_BH_Info 
where Convert(nvarchar(10), Day_get, 20) = @fd
and Cancel_Huy = 0
```